# sdk/request always responds with `constructor {}`

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox Add-on (SDK) and play around with the Request module. I copied-and-pasted the Twitter-API example from [Mozilla's documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) into my `lib/main.js`

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var latestTweetRequest = Request({
  url:   "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mozhacks&count=1",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    var tweet = response.json[0];
    console.log("User: " + tweet.user.screen_name);
    console.log("Tweet: " + tweet.text);
  }
});

Request({
  url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response); // <--- constructor {}
    if (response.json.remaining_hits) {
      latestTweetRequest.get();
    } else {
      console.log("You have been rate limited!");
    }
  }
}).get();
```

and start the extension with `cfx run`. Then, each response is just

```
constructor {}
```

and no error is thrown.

I set up a REST API on localhost and found that no requests are carried out.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that

```
constructor {}
```

is actually a correct response, rendered in a funny way in the terminal that executes `cfx run`. Things like `response.status` *do* work, as opposed to what one may be led to believe from the above output.

Comment: constructor {} is just the way how that response object is transformed to text in order to be shown with console.log, but still the object is a correct response as you figured out